# Referencing assets in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I started with an ASP.NET MVC Core 2.1 project. Then, I loaded a 3rd party theme (html/css/javascript/fonts) into wwwroot folder of the project. When I open the .html files from wwwroot, all appears fine.

I now want to "cut" the theme into MVC parts -- _Layout.html, views, etc. When html content is placed into MVC views, do I need to prefix every link with "~"? For example, href="css/colors/orange.css" becomes href="~/css/colors/orange.css"? This seems like a lot of work. Is there any way to tell .NET that relative paths are off wwwroot?

And a related question -- I don't have to use MVC - if I used ASP.NET Core non-MVC project, would this not be an issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The tilde is used to resolve virtual folders. For example, if I put my app in a virtual folder `app1` in IIS, then `href="~/path"` would be translated to `href="/app1/path"`. If you aren't using virtual folders then you shouldn't need the tilde.

**Additional**

`href="css/colors/orange.css"` is relative to the folder you are in. It is expecting `css` to be a child of the current folder. If you were to add a leading slash then it would be an implied absolute path with the leading slash being root. `href="/css/colors/orange.css"` would expect `css` to be a child of your root folder. If you aren't using virtual folders as explained above you would still need to add a leading slash since `css` will always be a child of root.